# Can't drop na with pandas read excel file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I try to remove all `NaN` rows from a dataframe which I get by `pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")`, I have tried with `df = df.dropna(how='all')` and `df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)`, both cannot remove the last empty rows which I printed as follows: `df.tail(1)`.

```
           a    b   c
3463      NaN  NaN
```

I noticed the value in column `c` is not null but empty. Someone could help to deal with this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you want replace empty values to missing before:

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True).dropna(how='all')
```

Regex `^\s+$` means:

- ^ is start of string
- \s+ is one or more whitespaces
- $ means end of string

Comment: Sorry, test with your method, it's still there.

Comment: @ahbon - is possible check problematic value? What return `df.loc[3463].tolist()` ?

Comment: `[nan, nan, '          ']`, I get this, it seems a big whitespace.

Comment: Thanks, your last edit works. Could you explain what `r'^\s+$'` means?

Answer (score 0):

Here `NaN` is also value and empty will also be treated as a part of row.

In case of `NaN`, you must drop or replace with something:

1. `dropna()`

If you use this function then whenever python finds `NaN` in a row, it will return `True` and will remove whole row, doesn't matter if any value is there or not besides `NaN`.

2. `fillna()` to fill some values instead of `NaN`

In your case :

```
df['C'].fillna(values="Any value")
```

Note: It is important to specify columns in which you want to fill values otherwise it will update whole dataframe respective to `NaN`

3. Now if there is empty row then try this :

`df[df['C']==" "]="Anyvalue"`

I have not tried this but my assumption on above is:

Lets break down:

a.  `df['C']==""`

This will return boolean values

b. `df[df['C']==""]="Anyvalue"`

wherever python finds `True`, value "Anyvalue" will get applied.